# Jquery: What's faster? .text() or .attr('id')?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, performance

just wondering, which of these would be faster?

```
if ( $(this).text() == 'Test' )
{ 
    ...
}
```

or

```
if ( $(this).attr('id') == 'Test' )
{
    ...
}
```

or is there a faster way?

or are they both the same?

thanks

Comment: I'm unsure why you're comparing text() with attr() - they're unrelated. Text returns the element's contents without HTML while attr is to get the element's attributes, such as its id. In terms of speed, direct is faster. If you could do it in assembly, it would be faster :)

Comment: @Christian, I think he has the option of storing data as text or as id.

Comment: thanks for your input guys! im just messing around with some code ideas really, trying to sort out my workflow :)

Answer (score 3):

By far the fastest would be `this.id === 'Test'`, an optimised version of `$(this).attr('id') == 'Test'`.

Note that this uses an object property, not `attr`, and the exact equality operator `===`.

NB that checking for the ID will be far, far faster, because `text()` (depending on your browser's capabilities) internally loops over every single child node and extracts its text value.  Checking for the ID requires only checking for one single attribute.

Answer (score 1):

To add to lonesomeday's answer, I'd point out that the correct answer is most likely "it doesn't matter". If it does, then you probably shouldn't be running such performance-critical code in the visitor's browser, and they might have misgivings about their processor time being used in such ways; remember, (client-side) JavaScript does not run on *your* computer!

Comment: thanks for the reply, thats ok, not running too performance heavy code, was just wondering really :)

Answer (score 0):

A simple [test](http://jsperf.com/text-vs-attr-id) shows that they're almost equally fast. `text()` seems to be *slightly* faster.

Comment: Actually the `.attr(id)` is faster, though only marginally, in your test. I've made the same mistake before, but the bigger the number reported, the faster. Plus, the difference in speed will be exaggerated when the number of nodes within `$(this)` increases beyond 1.

Comment: thanks for the link, was trying to find something like that before posting on here ;) i ran the test and it said that the .attr('id') was 22% faster than .text().

Comment: Box9 and David: Strange. I got text() to be 7% faster (for this particular test) on Chrome 8. And yes, this is only if the node doesn't contain any child elements. Child elements should slow the text() considerably.